# Ember.js – Binding a button action from an #each loop to its own model

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I can't seem to get a button, generated within an `#each` template loop, to bind its click action to its associated model. Here's a quick demo of the problem...

The `Ember.js` app setup:

```
window.Contacts = Ember.Application.create();

Contacts.Person = Ember.Object.extend({
    first: '',
    last: '',
    save: function() {
        // send updated information to server.
    }
});

Contacts.contactsList = Ember.ArrayController.create({
    content:[],
    init: function() {
        this.pushObject( Contacts.Person.create({
            first:'Tom',
            last:'Riddle'
        }));
    }
});
```

The template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
    {{#each Contacts.contactsList}}
    <li>
        {{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="first" viewName="firstname"}}
        {{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="last" viewName="lastname"}}
        <button {{action "save" on="click"}}>Save</button>
    </li>
    {{/each}}
</script>
```

The problem:

So, the idea in this simple demo scenario is that the "Save" button for each record will trigger an action to save the state of its own model. However, clicking the Save button gives an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'call' of undefined
```

My assumption would be that specifying "save" as the button's action would bind it to the `save` method on its model. However, this does not appear to be the case. Some other object appears to be handling click actions, wherein a "save" hander is undefined. Am I missing something here? How could I make each line item's button call a handler on its own model?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 10):

You can define a target of an action by setting the - surprise - `target` property, see http://jsfiddle.net/pangratz666/FukKX/:

```html
<script type="text/x-handlebars" >
    {{#each Contacts.contactsList}}
    <li>
        {{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="first" viewName="firstname"}}
        {{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="last" viewName="lastname"}}
        {{#with this as model}}
            <button {{action "save" target="model"}}>Save</button>
        {{/with}}
    </li>
    {{/each}}
</script>​
```

The `{{#with}}` helper around the action is needed because somehow the action helper does not accept `this` as a `target`.

---

But a note to your design: actions should be called on views or on a controller. The target is then responsible for executing further actions like saving, ...

So I would implement your example as follows, see http://jsfiddle.net/pangratz666/U2TKJ/:

**Handlebars**:

```html
<script type="text/x-handlebars" >
    {{#each Contacts.contactsList}}
    <li>
        {{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="first" viewName="firstname"}}
        {{view Ember.TextField valueBinding="last" viewName="lastname"}}
        <button {{action "save" target="Contacts.contactsController" }}>Save</button>
    </li>
    {{/each}}
</script>​
```

**JavaScript**:

```js
Contacts.contactsController = Ember.Object.create({
    save: function(event) {
        console.log('do something with: ', event.context);
    }
});
```

Comment: Global lookup is deprecated

Answer (score 2):

There´re two possible ways

```
{{#each answer in effort_reasons itemController="module_answer"}}
{{/each}}
```

So each Item gets its own controller where model is the each item (in this case answer), this is especially usefull for something like an Input View where valueBinding would result in binding every input view to the same value. Note this is the only time where controllers in Ember are not singletons, and are having different ID´s, if you want to save your values in the original controller you can get a reference via

```
this.get('controller.parentController')
```

inside your itemController.

Or you use the mentioned action approach inside the each loop with

```
{{action "actionname" parameter paramter2...}}
```